# Google Cloud Datastore Emulator does not use default credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Per [Google's Cloud Datastore Emulator installation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator), I was able to install and run the emulator in a *bash* terminal window without problem with `gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project gramm-id`.

I also setup the environment variables, [per the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#automatically_setting_the_variables), in another terminal with `$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)` and verified they were defined.

However, when I run my python script to add an entity to the local datastore with this code:

```py
from google.cloud import datastore

print(os.environ['DATASTORE_HOST'])          # output: http://localhost:8081
print(os.environ['DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST']) # output: localhost:8081


client = datastore.Client('gramm-id')
kind = 'Task'
name = 'simpleTask'

task_key = client.key(kind, name)
task = client.Enity(key=task_key)
task['description'] = 'Buy milk'
client.put(task)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools.py", line 237, in <module>
    client = datastore.Client('gramm-id')
  File "/home/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py", line 205, in __init__
    project=project, credentials=credentials, _http=_http)
... long stack trace ....
  File "/home/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

I don't think I need to [create a GCP service account and provide access credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) to use the datastore emulator on my machine.

My system:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Anaconda python 3.6.6
- Google Cloud SDK 215.0.0
- cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> gcloud auth application-default login

This will prompt you to login through a browser window and will set your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS correctly for you. [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#calling)

Comment: I got this error then: "UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/ warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)"

Comment: I am checking this link https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5738 which denotes using "client = datastore.Client(_http=requests.Session)" to avoid asking for creds, I am not sure if it now works because I authenticated via browser or because it actually works!

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to use mock credentials, e.g.:

```
class EmulatorCreds(google.auth.credentials.Credentials):

    def __init__(self):
        self.token = b'secret'
        self.expiry = None

    @property
    def valid(self):
        return True

    def refresh(self, _):
        raise RuntimeError('Should never be refreshed.')

client = datastore.Client(
    project='gramm-id',
    credentials=EmulatorCreds() , 
    _http=requests.Session()  # Un-authorized
)
```

However [it seems like this doesn't currently work](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3920), so for now you'll need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`